# Is this a bug of boost regex?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I wanna match any chars like a-z,A-Z,0-9,and -, so I wrote this:

```
#include "thirdparty/boost/regex.hpp"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(){
    string reg = "[a-z-A-Z0-9]";
    boost::regex expression(reg);
    cout<<"OK"<<endl;
}
```

when running, program core dumped and says:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
  what():  Invalid range end in character class  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression: '[a-z->>>HERE>>>A-Z0-9]'.

who can tell me why?

Comment: Did you try this regex in anything else, such as your text editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause of this is the hyphen (`-`) after the first range inside your character class. Inside of a character class the hyphen has **special** meaning. You can place the hyphen as the first or last character of the class.

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9]
[a-zA-Z0-9-]
```

In some regular expression implementations, you can also place directly after a range.

If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to escape it in order to add it to your class.

Actual regular expression implementation:

```
[a-z\-A-Z0-9]
```

As a string literal:

```
string reg = "[a-z\\-A-Z0-9]";
```

Comment: I found that [-a-zA-Z0-9],[a-zA-Z0-9-] or [a-z\-A-Z0-9] all works except [a-z-A-Z0-9]. [a-z-A-Z0-9] works in perl and python, boost regex claim it takes the same syntax as perl, but maybe this is a little difference.

Comment: +1, but it only takes one backslash to escape the hyphen.  The second backslash becomes necessary when you write the regex in the form of a C string literal.  If you write it with two backslashes, you should include the quotes as well.  Even better, write it both ways -- actual regex: `[a-z\-A-Z0-9]`; as string literal: `"[a-z\\-A-Z0-9]"`.